# For loop over dictionary in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Is there a proper way to loop over a dictionary in RF?
I used pythonic way, but failed:

```
:FOR  ${key}  ${value}  IN  &{dict}
```

output:
    Number of FOR loop values should be multiple of its variables. Got 2 variables but 1 value.

Same, when i pointed dictionary as scalar variable. I couldn't find an example in documentation though.
Has anyone solved that?

P.S.

I am aware of workaround solution, that you use kw. Get Dictionary Keys and Get Dictionary Values, then, to update values you use Set To Dictionary  ${key}  ${new_value}, but this seems to be human unfriendly and uses several for loops iterations instead one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Loop Through Dict
    &{mydict}    Create Dictionary    a=1    b=2
    :FOR    ${key}    IN    @{mydict.keys()}
    \    Log    ${mydict["${key}"]}

Loop Through Dict And Multiplicate Values
    &{mydict}    Create Dictionary    a=1    b=2
    :FOR    ${key}    IN    @{mydict.keys()}
    \    ${new_value}    Evaluate    ${mydict["${key}"]}*2
    \    Set To Dictionary   ${mydict}    ${key}=${new_value}
    Log    ${mydict}
```

Comment: this is the workaround I mentioned. It's not so bad in your example, but try to e.g. multiply values by number and update... In python still one for loop, here... terrible. This even might be forwarded to RF team as improvement.

Comment: Hmm, then I don't understand. You can loop through list of dictionary keys by `:FOR    ${key}    IN    @{dict.keys()}` or through list of dictionary values by `:FOR    ${value}    IN    @{dict.values()}` without any other additional keyword.

Comment: Ah, now after you extended the comment it is more clear. Yeah, it is unpleasant to do such loop in RF, I would definitely write as many KWs as possible in python.

Comment: Anyway you can update the dictionary in single loop as in edited answer.

Comment: Still much worse approach than in Python (i mean RF), but you've made it as nice as possible, thank you :)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Why to not write the keyword in python and call it from RF test? I would write most of code in python.

Comment: "Set To Dictionary" I am not getting this keyword in robotframework-selenium library. Is this keyword deprecated from the Library ?
when I am using "Set To Dictionary" I am getting UNKNOWN KEYWORD error for it.

Answer (score 10):

To iterate over a dictionary's keys, you don't have to use any python method at all, but insted use the Robotframework's `@` modifier for list expansion. For example:

```
${mydict}    Create Dictionary    a=1    b=2
:FOR    ${key}    IN    @{mydict}
\    Log     The current key is: ${key}
# there are at least to ways to get the value for that key
# "Extended variable syntax", e.g. direct access:
\    Log     The value is: ${mydict['${key}']}
# or using a keyword from the Collections library:
\    ${value}=    Get From Dictionary    ${mydict}    ${key}
\    Log     The value through Collections is: ${value}
```

The loop over the keys works straightaway, because in python a `list()` cast of a dictionary is actually the list of its keys. Sample code:

```
mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(list(mydict))
# the output is 
# ['a', 'b']
```

---

There is a python's dict method `items()` that iterates over the dictionary and returns a tuple of key, value. Regretfully, there is no direct substitute in Robot Framework's for loops, yet - this can be done with [the `Get Dictionary Items` keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Get%20Dictionary%20Items). It returns a one-dimensional list, in the form

```
['key1', value_of_key1, 'key2', value_of_key2,]
```

Combining that with the `@` list expansion, you can get both the key and the value in each cycle:

```
${mydict}    Create Dictionary      a=1    b=2
${items}     Get Dictionary Items   ${mydict}

:FOR    ${key}    ${value}    IN    @{items}
\    Log     The current key is: ${key}
\    Log     The value is: ${value}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround is to use the keyword "Get From Dictionary" during the for loop.

```
Loop through and Log key and value in dict
    [Documentation]    Loops through each key and stores the key value 
    ...                in a variable that can be used during the for 
    ...                loop, as if you were iterating through python 
    ...                with "for key, value in dict.iteritems()".
    &{mydict}    Create Dictionary    a=1    b=2
    :FOR    ${key}    IN    @{mydict.keys()}
    \    ${value}=    Get From Dictionary    ${mydict}    ${key}
    \    Log    ${key}, ${value}
```

reference: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Get%20From%20Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

check solutions:

```
:FOR    ${key}    IN    @{mydict}
# works as @{mydict.keys()}

:FOR    ${key}    ${value}    IN    @{mydict.items()}
# doesn't work at all
```

Found another solutions which works:

```
:FOR    ${key}     ${value}    IN ZIP    ${mydict.keys()}    ${mydict.values()}

# And another less readable (can work without setters)
:FOR    ${el}    IN    @{mydict.items()}   
\    ${key}=    Set Variable    ${el[0]}
\    ${value}=    Set Variable    ${el[1]}
```

Comment: In python version before 3.6 (that includes all 2.x version) the order of dictionaries is not guaranteed; thus calling `${mydict.keys()}    ${mydict.values()}` simultaneously may very well return you one key, and the value of a different one.

Answer (score 2):

```
FOR    ${key}    ${value}    IN    &{dictionary}
    Log To Console   key = ${key}, value = ${value}
END
```

This works fine in [RF 3.2.2](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dictionary-iteration)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (RF: 3.2.+):

```
FOR    ${key_value}    IN    @{mydict.items()}
        ${key}=  set variable  ${key_value}[0]
        ${value}=  set variable  ${key_value}[1]
        log  Key: ${key}; Value: ${value}
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this version more readable (with RF 3.2+)

```
FOR    ${key}    IN    @{mydict.items()}
    Log To Console    ${key}: ${mydict}[${key}]
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
FOR  ${key}  IN  @{res.keys()}
      Log    ${key}    
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do that trick without loop in today’s version of Robot Framework

```
&{dict}=  Create dictionary key1=aaa     key2=bbb
&{updates}=  Create dictionary key1=xxx key2=zzz

Set to Dictionary    ${dict}    &{updates}
Should Be Equal   ${dict}[key1]   xxx
Should Be Equal   ${dict}[key2]   zzz
```

Comment: Question was asked almost 7y ago.... I dont think (don't know now), if your solution was available even back there (neverthelesss it's good to have it in SO)

Comment: Yes I did not realize how long ago was the question and this is very useful