# Is it good to use ROBOT Framework for Restful API Automation

Tags: python, robotframework

I have an Automation Repository for my project, which contains 5-6 Library files, some config files, job files and around 300 testcases all written in Python, testcases using unittest package of python. 
Now i want to port all these testcases to some framework, so that it can give me some basic functionalities for emailing , scaling and Job running.
Will it be helpful to use Robot Framework for this? 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Robot Framework supports REST APIs using [`RequestsLibrary`](http://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/).

Sample program, you can check below:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     REST API Testcase
Library           RequestsLibrary
Library           String
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
${headers}        ${Empty}
${AliasName}      CLM

*** Test Cases ***
GetRequestAPI
    [Tags]    Sanity
    Create the Session    ${AliasName}    ${GetReqURL}
    ${headers}=    Create the Header    ${contentType}    ${authorizationFlag}
    ${resp}=    Get the Request    ${AliasName}    ${GetReqURI}    ${headers}
    Verify the Response    ${Resp}    ${GetReqStatusCode}

PostRequestAPI
    Create the Session    ${AliasName}    ${PostReqURL}
    ${headers}=    Create the Header    ${contentType}    ${authorizationFlag}
    ${resp}=    Post the Request    ${AliasName}    ${PostReqURI}    ${PostReqData}    ${headers}
    Verify the Response    ${Resp}    ${PostReqStatusCode}

*** Keywords ***
Verify the Response
    [Arguments]    ${response}    ${resp_status}
    Log    Response code is : ${response.status_code}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${response.status_code}    ${resp_status}
    Log    Response body is : ${response.text}
```

Hope, this will be helpful

Comment: Can i use my existing Library files written in python for the testcases. I'm completely new to Robot, so please excuse me for the silly question, i'm still weighing my options for choosing a framework

Comment: Did you tried to read the doc? Start here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html

Comment: yes, you can use , by creating your own python files as custom library to `robotframework` and use those functions as keywords in `robotframework`, as @Jan suggested please go through the documentation of robotframework

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that document.Thanks for all your suggestions

Comment: I started with the Robot Framework, using my existing python Libraries    `*** Settings ***
Library  ../../lib/ServerAPI.py  WITH NAME  ServerAPI

*** Test Cases ***
[TC-001]-Registering a device with INVALID SUBSCRIBER name to the server

    ServerAPI.subscriber  None
    ${resp}  register device  ${token}  ${devid}
    LOG  ${resp}
    Should Be Equal    ${resp}    ${True}`     Its not recognising the ServerAPI keyword name for the library, can anybody help me, what i'm missing here?

Comment: please check whether the path of *.py file is in `path` environment variables

Answer (score 1):

If  you  only  use   Robot Framework for  REST API automation it  can work well. However robotframework has many external libraries which map to file operations, string manipulation and more. https://robotframework.org/#libraries

In my experience chaining together these libs into your own libs and keywords results in system test environment which is  difficult to debug. The external libraries map to python libraries and it is better to use the python libs directly in your own  libs because it removes a layer of abstraction.

For  example at robotframework loop syntax and how you define variable scope. It is  not as readable as normal python and you do not have things such as generators  and  itertools available.

[For loop over dictionary in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228908/for-loop-over-dictionary-in-robot-framework)